# Change user agent from Android manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, user-agent

I am building a small web app for contact and because some of the data will be access via www i dont want non-android user to go to the site.

my idea is to change the user agent so when i go to the site, i read the user agent and can detect if it comes from the app or not.

here the manifest i have now (copied from the android website)

i have also the assets/www/index.html (and other files there)

is there an option in the manifest to change that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myproject"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <permission android:name="myproject"></permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sample" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.android.basiccontactables.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use manifest to change `WebView`s user agent. You should use `WebSettings` in Java code instead, specifically its [setUserAgentString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29) method. Use it something like this:

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android");
```

Comment: thanks, i have no idea what to do on that part since i only have an html site now. ill dig thanks